# Pass AjaxHelper.ActionLink from the server to the view in a model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

In ASP.NET MVC 3, I would like to be able to create an enumerable of AjaxHelper.ActionLink on the server, add it to a model, and bind the model to a view.  The view would then have a dynamic number of ActionLink.

When I try to instantiate a new AjaxHelper in my controller action, it needs things like a ViewContext and an IViewDataContainer, so I'm getting a little stumped.

Ideally I would like to have some factory that does the work of determining how to construct the ActionLink, how many to construct, and which returns a ViewResult or ActionResult.

I've done some digging around, but can't seem to find if this is possible or an acceptable pattern...

Hopefully this is pretty clear, but I'm happy to clarify if not!

Comment: rather than create the action links in the controller, why not just hold the values in an array within the model, and loop through that array in the view using the values to create the action links?

Comment: If I did it that way, I would still need to have a defined number of ActionLinks in the view, whereas ideally I would like the view to not know how many it will get...  If the model actually contained the ActionLinks, I was hoping to do a foreach over the enumerable and just slap em on the page.

Comment: Sorry Slicksim, I see that I was wrong - I could have a foreach in the view that constructs ActionLinks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom view called

AjaxLinksPartial.cshtml

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") @*You need this included, probably in your main layout*@
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<div id ="Target"></div>

@{foreach (var link in Model.LinkItems)
 {
    @Ajax.ActionLink(link.Text, link.Action, link.Controller, null, Model.AjaxOptions, Model.HtmlAttrbs)
 }
}
```

with a backing model AjaxLinks

```
public class AjaxLinks
{
    public List<LinkItem> LinkItems { get; set; }
    public AjaxOptions AjaxOptions { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Object> HtmlAttrbs { get; set; }

    public AjaxLinks(AjaxOptions options, Dictionary<string, Object> htmlAttrbutes)
    {
        LinkItems = new List<LinkItem>();
        this.AjaxOptions = options;
        this.HtmlAttrbs = htmlAttrbutes;
    }
}
public class LinkItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }

    public LinkItem(string Text, string Controller, string Action)
    {
        this.Text = Text;
        this.Controller = Controller;
        this.Action = Action;
    }
}
```

use it as follows in the controller

```
        var htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
        htmlAttributes.Add("class", "linkstyling class");
        var ajaxOptions = new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "Target", HttpMethod = "POST"};
        var links = new AjaxLinks(ajaxOptions, htmlAttributes);
        links.LinkItems.Add(new LinkItem("About","Home","About"));
```

and render it within another view

```
 @Html.Partial("AjaxLinksPartial", Model)
```

the main downside is this isn't a clean separation of styling and other concerns. If you are able to remake this cleanly using HtmlHelpers, I would be very interested. PM me or comment if you do.